# How to find the values which would equate the division between two numbers of swapped digits without knowing anything further?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems, cryptarithm

I'm having difficulty in assess this problem in a method without relying too much in too many trial and error. I have noticed there is a similar puzzle but in such it includes the value of one of the digits, but how do you solve this without knowing any other information?.

The problem is as follows:

> Using the expression from below:
>
> $$\frac{\overline{ASIR}}{\overline{RISA}}=4$$
>
> Find $\overline{RI}-\overline{SA}$

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{75}\\
2.&\textrm{-75}\\
3.&\textrm{57}\\
4.&\textrm{-57}\\
5.&\textrm{-48}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should this problem be assesed without just guessing?. Can someone help me with this?.

So far the only thing which I could come up with was with the following:

$\overline{ASIR}=4\overline{RISA}$

$1000A+100S+10I+R=4000R+400I+40S+4A$

From this it can be obtained:

$996A+60S=3996R+390I$

But that's it. That's the place where I came stuck. From then on I think its just trial and error, but on looking on the equation all letters with the exception of R and A can take values between 1 to 9. So how to constrain those or to solve this thing in a more orderly manner?. Can someone help me with a **step-by-step approach and the most detailed as possible**?.

Comment: @TobyMak Not exactly, the question stems into the direction of solving it without relying on algebraic approach. The part where I'm stuck on doesn't really analyze that and hence I requested such assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it as $\overline {ASIR} \times 4 = \overline {RISA}$.  Note that $A$ can only be $1$ or $2$ because otherwise multiplying by $4$ would carry.  It has to be $2$ because it is the ones digit of the product.  Now $R$ must be $3$ or $8$ to make the $A$ in the product, and it must be $8$ because it is at least $4$.  We are left with $\overline {SI} \times 4 +3=\overline {IS}$, so $S$ is odd and must be $1$ to avoid a carry.  Then $I$ must be $7$ and we have $2178 \times 4 = 8712$

Comment: Interesting approach, I had totally overlooked that $A$ could only be $1$ or $2$ by looking it at the far left side in the number. But the rest it is too condensed to follow. Perhaps can you expand it a little bit to understand it better?. I'm stuck on it has to be $2$ and the rest. Can you do that please?.

Comment: Write out the multiplication.  The ones digit of the product must be even because there can't be a carry in and the multiplier is $4$.  Then what digits can be multiplied by $4$ to get something ending in $2$?  Only $3$ and $8$.  These puzzles are called cryptarithms.  They call for great facility with single digit arithmetic.

Comment: Well I did what you said and got to the same answer. I am familiar with these kind of puzzles. But as mentioned, it can be problematic when there isn't many clues. In this peculiar problem maybe it is eased because the digits in the product also appear in one of the factors which constrains the choices.

Comment: That sort of thing is what makes it a reasonable puzzle.  If the only way to solve it is brute force, it isn't a good puzzle.

Comment: Although the question is closed its very nice of you to have assisted me, and which by the way your approach was very easy to follow.